# Instantiate enemy when I pick an item

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine

I want to instantiate an enemy when my player pick an item just in this place but I don't get it. This is the code I place in the item.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class SpawnEnemies : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject spawnPosition;
    public GameObject spawnObject;


    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "player"){
            Instantiate(spawnObject, spawnPosition.transform.position, spawnPosition.transform.rotation);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No error in console but it doesn't instantiate the object when the player enters on the trigger

Comment: Are you sure the value of `spawnPosition.transform.position` is correct? Set a breakpoint there and see if that code block is entered at all.

Comment: I've done but nothing appears in console :(

Comment: try GameObject whatever = (GameObject)Instantiate(spaw....); and then take a look at "whatever" GO. It can be misplaced / disabled / invisible / fallen out of render engine as of physics / destroyed on spawn because of some bug, etc.
It's also possible your "if" is never true. Put in a line of Debug.Log("mwuhaha!"); inside the if, before the Instantiate call

Comment: Yes ! It was an error in the values of the player collider. Thank you so much !!